# Trying to scrape a specific part of html with Python-3.7, but it returns "None"

Tags: html, web-scraping, python-3.7

I am a beginner writing some simple Python code to scrape data from a web page.  I have located the exact part of the html that I want to scrape, but it keeps returning "None."  It works for other parts of the web page, but not this one specific part

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse the html, and since I can scrape some of the code, I am assuming I will not need to use Selenium.  But I still cannot find how to scrape one specific part.

Here is the Python code I have written:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.rent.com/new-york/tuckahoe-apartments?page=2'

response = requests.get(url)

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

apt_listings = html_soup.find_all('div', class_='_3RRl_')
print(type(apt_listings))
print(len(apt_listings))

first_apt = apt_listings[0]

first_apt.a

first_add = first_apt.a.text

print(first_add)


apt_rents = html_soup.find_all('div', class_='_3e12V')
print(type(apt_rents))
print(len(apt_rents))

first_rent = apt_rents[0]

print(first_rent)

first_rent = first_rent.find('class', attrs={'data-tid' : 'price'})

print(first_rent)
```

Here is the output from CMD:

```
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
30
address not disclosed
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
30
<div class="_3e12V" data-tid="price">$2,350</div>
None
```

The "address not disclosed" is correct and was scraped successfully.  ***I want to scrape the $2,350 but it keeps returning "None."***  I think I am close to getting it right but I just can't seem to get the $2,350.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the property .text of BeautifulSoup instead .find() like this:

```
first_rent = first_rent.text
```

as simple as that.

Comment: Thank you JacopoDT.  I tried what you suggested, and it returned an error: `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
30
address not disclosed
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
30
<div class="_3e12V" data-tid="price">$2,350</div>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bvilleaptsprelim.py", line 39, in <module>
    first_rent = first_rent.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: i expressed myself badly, you should use .text not after .find() but instead of it.

Comment: Thank you again, but it's still not working: `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
30
address not disclosed
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
30
<div class="_3e12V" data-tid="price">$2,350</div>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bvilleaptsprelim.py", line 37, in <module>
    first_rent = first_rent.text('class', attrs={'data-tid' : 'price'})
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: no, .text is a propery, not a method, change `first_rent = first_rent.find('class', attrs={'data-tid' : 'price'})` with `first_rent = first_rent.text`

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all the listings from a script tag and parse as json. The regex looks for this script tag which starts `window.__APPLICATION_CONTEXT__ =`.

[image]

The string after that is extracted via the group in the regex `(.*)`. That javascript object can be parsed as json if the string is loaded with json.loads.

You can explore the json object [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=bb51da5bdb0644f981b57bd18c712afd)

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
base_url = 'https://www.rent.com/'
res = requests.get('https://www.rent.com/new-york/tuckahoe-apartments?page=2')
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
r = re.compile(r'window.__APPLICATION_CONTEXT__ = (.*)')
data = soup.find('script', text=r).text
script = r.findall(data)[0]
items = json.loads(script)['store']['listings']['listings']
results = []

for item in items:   
    address = item['address']
    area = ', '.join([item['city'], item['state'], item['zipCode']])
    low_price = item['aggregates']['prices']['low']
    high_price = item['aggregates']['prices']['high']
    listingId = item['listingId']
    url = base_url + item['listingSeoPath']
    # all_info = item
    record = {'address' : address,
              'area' : area,
              'low_price' : low_price,
              'high_price' : high_price,
              'listingId' : listingId,
              'url' : url}
    results.append(record)
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = [ 'address', 'area', 'low_price', 'high_price', 'listingId', 'url'])
print(df)
```

---

Sample of results:

[image]

---

Short version with class:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.rent.com/new-york/tuckahoe-apartments?page=2'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('._3e12V').text)
```

---

All prices:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.rent.com/new-york/tuckahoe-apartments?page=2'
response = requests.get(url)

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print([item.text for item in html_soup.select('._3e12V')])
```

Comment: QHarr, incredible, thank you very much.  While that is ultimately what I want to do, I don't understand the code, as I mentioned, I am a beginner.  I am working toward that by learning how to scrape each one separately to better understand how the code works.  I appreciate your elegant solution, but, any chance you can tell me a simple fix to scraping just that one bit?  Thank you again!

Comment: html_soup.select_one('._3e12V').text

Comment: That works also...and...I understand it!  Thank you QHarr!